# How do I create a java.sql.Date object initialized to current time? It keeps getting rounded off to midnight time

Tags: java

I am trying to create a `java.sql.Date` object initialized to current time but it was being rounded off to midnight time . Can any of you help? I attempted below but it did not work.

```
new Date(new java.util.Date().getTime())
```

Comment: `java.sql.Date` is actually a date.  It has no time component.

Comment: Basically I am using jdbc tio insert date into database column which supports both date and time components. How do I do I insert current time to statement like below.                                   preparedStatement.setDate(3,xxx);

Comment: Is this column a TIMESTAMP type?  If so, `java.sql.Timestamp` is what you want.

Comment: I have downvoted this question as you have shown no evidence of research.

Answer (score 2):

I can't explain it better than the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) does:

> A thin wrapper around a millisecond value that allows JDBC to identify this as an SQL DATE value. A milliseconds value represents the number of milliseconds that have passed since January 1, 1970 00:00:00.000 GMT.
>
> To conform with the definition of SQL DATE, the millisecond values wrapped by a java.sql.Date instance must be 'normalized' by setting the hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds to zero in the particular time zone with which the instance is associated.

If you need time information as well, you might use `java.sql.Timestamp`.